# Groovy MissingPropertyException in build.gradle file

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, jar

I'm trying to include some local jars in my build.gradle file:

```
def dir = new File("/some/file/path")
def libList = new ArrayList()
dir.eachDir {libList.add(it)}
libList.sort()

buildscript {
repositories {

    for (item in libList) {
        maven {
            name = "injected_offline_${item.name}"
            url = item.toURI().toURL()
        }
    }
}
```

}

But I keep getting the following error:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'libList' for repository container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultRepositoryHandler.
```

Comment: can you move the def part (4 lines) inside. the `buildscript{` and try

Comment: tried but this comes up  `Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:`

Comment: go for groovy list initialization like [] -> def libList = []